# octave package install not successful for windows

Tags: windows, package, installation, octave, nan

[Hello, I have a question that i cannot install the package for OCTAVE by the package from here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/?source=typ_redirect
My system is windows. please help me.

> > pkg install nan-3.1.4.tar.gz
> >     ls: /usr/local/: No such file or directory
> >     ][1]

Comment: Since you are running Windows, you might want to try the Windows version rather than the packages for linux.

Comment: @picciano there are no "packages for linux". The .tar.gz packages contain sourcecode which needs to be built on the host and ideally should compile in *nixes and windoze

Comment: @Andy if the package is trying to use /use/local/ls, it means that the package is bugged, right?

Comment: @HAL9000 yes, I think the bug is in src/Makefile.in around line 73 where it is tried to detect an existing MATLAB installation. But since the nan package is typically crosscompiled on GNU/Linux for target windoze, nobody stumbled over this yet. Please submit a bugreport for the NaN package if you want to build it natively (not using the binaries in the MXE installer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install from https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/#install using the installer. It includes many octave-forge packages (including nan) so the only thing you need is to `pkg load io`